# How might I render a JSON string for a dynamic rails route?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I've been setting up a tagging system for a post. I am using the awesome Select2 gem. One thing that I've noticed is that when I go to edit a post, **the tags for that post do not show up.** I found a way to **get tags to pre-populate using the val() function**.

However, because my **edit route** which is users/:user_id/post/:id **is** inherently **dynamic**, **it makes it difficult to use a string for the **.getJSON***.*

How might I do this or do it differently?

Please note I purposely did not fill in a correct JSON path for the first .getJSON.. this is where I am having difficulty.

```
var items = [];
var prepopulate = [];

$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/[JSON PATH HERE]', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        return prepopulate.push(obj.name);
        });

  $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/tags.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
          return items.push(obj.name);
          });
      $("#post_tag_ids").val(prepopulate).select2({
    width: "element",
    tags: items,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what that first JSON response is supposed to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bricker, it's ok.. using RABL this can be done with ease. For anyone interested check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl